# Parse Javascript variables from String to JSON in React/Typescript

Tags: javascript, json, typescript, react-native, react-typescript

I want to read data embedded into a JavaScript-File with React-Native/Typescript. I'm reading the JS-File into a String and was playing around with regex but couldn't get this to work.

String:

```
SomeInfo=[{key:"some text with ;"}];SomeOtherInfo={56:23};SomeMoreInfo=7654321345;EvenMoreInfo=[{somekey:"some value"}];
```

The string itself is basically a one-liner. no line-breaks. whitespaces are only available in some values enclosed in double quotes (see above). The list of key-value pairs in the above example is not complete, so there might be more, always separated by `;`.

I was able to use this regex

```
/([^=]+)=([^;]+)/gm
```

for a "generic" version to match `key=value` into groups but this does not work if the separator `;` is part of any value (like in my example above).

With this regex:

```
/(?![SomeInfo=])(.*)(?=;SomeOtherInfo=)/gm
```

I am able to extract everything between those specific keys but then I am stuck with `JSON.parse()` as the keys are expected to be enclosed in quotes which is not the case.

How can I actually get all of those key-value pairs parsed as JSON?
Is it even possible to come up with a generic regex that also takes care of the quote issue of certain keys?

Any help appreciated, thanks!

Comment: What are you trying to achieve exactly? Sounds like [x-y problem](https://xyproblem.info/).

Comment: as I said I want to work with the data that is embedded in this string. possibly put it into an ui for a cross-platform app. what would also work: directly import this js file  from a remote (http) url and use its structures directly?

Comment: Yes, I actually thought about the second solution you suggest.

Comment: couldn't get that import to work from a remote url.

Comment: I understand that the you read the external data as a string, and then want to parse it as js code?

Comment: yes, that's correct.